# Xamarin.Forms Prism master view not showing hamburger icon when popover visible

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail, prism-6

I have set up my Xamarin.Forms Prism application to use a Master-Detail Page (with MasterBehavior set to Popover) for its navigation, but I am noticing a few differences between my Prism app and the sample Xamarin.Forms app using this page (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/).

On Android, clicking the hamburger icon makes the master slide out in both apps.  In the sample app, the hamburger icon remains visible.  In my Prism app, the hamburger icon does not remain visible, as the master view takes the full height of the screen, as shown below:

[image: Android]

On UWP, clicking the hamburger icon makes the master slide out in both apps.  In the sample app, the hamburger icon remains visible and the title of the master page is shown at the top.  In my Prism app, neither of these items are visible, as shown below:

[image: UWP]

There also appears to be some type of padding or empty space at the top and bottom of the Prism app master view.

Are these differences introduced by Prism itself, or is there a way to configure the master to behave similar to the vanilla Xamarin.Forms sample?

---

UPDATED SCREENSHOTS

To better demonstrate the issue that I am seeing, here are some more screenshots.

Xamarin sample, app launch and then hitting the hamburger icon keeps the navigation bar (with hamburger icon) visible with the master visible:

[image: Xam]

My Prism app, app launch and then hitting the hamburger icon makes the master view take up the entire height of the screen:

[image: Prism]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the hamburger icon to show when you navigation to a page you have to wrap the Detail in a NavigationPage.  So register the navigationPage for navigation, and then add it to your navigation URI.

```
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyMasterDetail/NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }
```

Take a look at this sandbox example:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin

Comment: I currently have a similar setup and can see the hamburger icon.  The screenshots are from when I have tapped the hamburger icon and the master view popover has appeared...the hamburger icon isn't there to tap again and make the master view go away.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem 100%. Maybe you need to change the MasterBehavior property. Prism does nothing regarding icons or modifying the displaying of pages. So this is not a Prism issue https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/#Controlling_the_Detail_Page_Display_Behavior

Comment: I added a couple more screenshots to show the differences I am seeing.  When I take my master-detail page out of my Prism app, it works as it does in Xamarin's sample app, so I'm not sure if there is something Prism-related that I need to do to keep the navigation bar visible when the master is displayed, or something else is going on.

Comment: Ohhhh.... now I see.  This could be because the sample is using an older version of Xamarin that uses FormsApplicationActivity.  The new templates use FormsAppCompatActivity with material design.  If you create a new project with the Xamarin.Forms template and try this you will get the exact same behavior as with the Prism app. Like I said, Prism has nothing to do with how the slide out of the master behaves.